# weird table slide dimensions?

Tags: repair, table, measuring, extension

We have a round table that can take two leaves, however, the two table extension slides (I think that's what they're called?) are irreparably broken, and seem to be a non-standard size, but I'm not sure.

The table leaves are each 13 3/4", so 27.5" total.  The table opening is 29" (with 25" x 3 piece slides).  Given the dimensions of the table, it can't really take a slide much larger (26", maybe 27").  The current slide is 25" x 3, with a 54" extension when fully extended.

However, I can't seem to find any slides that are this kind of dimension.  I have found a number of 26" slides with a max opening of 51-52", but all of them state 2 12" leaves, which seems too small.

I guess my question is: am I looking for the wrong thing?  Could I make the smaller slide work?  I'm concerned about the opening width and the width of the leaves.

Comment: What am I missing here? You say that your two leaves together would add 27.5" to the table. Yet these 26" slides you found will open out to 51"-52". That seems way more opening than needed to set in your two leaves side by side and still have 23.5"-24.5" left over.

Comment: the 51"-52" includes the parts mounted to the the two halves of the table.  The concern is the actual gap (according to the specs) is only 25" or 26".  (13" on each side under the table, that's 26 of the 51 or 52.)